# Destroy the binding between a jquery function and my object?

Tags: jquery, binding

If i use some really simple code like :

```
$('#elm').tipTip();
```

It will do what the plugin is intended for. Is there a way to **destroy** this binding to the plugin `tipTip()` will no long bind itself to this element?

**UPDATE**

The reason is, it's not that I want to stop the tips from popping up, I have one main data div that the user sees, and as they click around the content from hidden divs is moved into it with a snazzy transition.

The plugin works great once, but then if I remove the content and then add it back in again (click something else and then back again) they don't work.

I assumed the best thing was to remove the whole tip plugin binding from my element and then start again every time the content is moved into the box, perhaps not.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548426/unbind-jquery-plugins

Comment: I'm not using the editable() though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first if asking such a question it would be nice if you include a link to the plugin your are using. Is this the [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) you mean? If yes:

As far as I can see this plugin doesn't have the functionality built in to "destroy" a already created TipTip object. (At least there is no notion of this in the documentation and the source code too on quick inspection doesn't offer this).

As I'm not familiar with the plugin itself and you didn't detail how you are using it I'm not sure my solution will work out for you. But you can try and then give feedback if it did.

This should stop the tip tip from showing up.

```
$('#elem').unbind('hover');
```

Problems with this solution:

- It only unbinds the event the plugin binds itself to
- The TipTip object isn't really removed but just no longer triggered
- This won't work if you yourself have bound another handler to the hover event of this element

If there is only one element on your page with the TipTip functionality you might consider removing the additional DOM stuff the plugin uses too

```
$("div[id^=tiptip_]").remove(); //remove the tiptip holder/content/arrow divs
```

Comment: Thats the plugin, i have adjusted the question above.

Comment: @jitter, I've browse through the plugin source code as well, there's no implementation for  users to destroy or unbind it.

Comment: Nope it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Doesn't work with unbind('hover'), but does with unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')

Answer (score 1):

I found just rebind `tipTip()` to the element and it will override the old tip.