# unattach a jQuery function from a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

is this possible?

Like when you have a lightbox plugin: `$('.foo').lightbox()`

Can you remove lightbox() from all `.foo'`s, or only from specific a `.foo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this interesting [Unbinding Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548426/unbind-jquery-plugins)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it two ways. One is to remove it from $ altogether - probably not what you want - by doing

```
$.lightbox = null;
```

If you want to do it to a set of elements, you would need to do this:

```
var elements = $('.foo');
elements.lightbox = null;
```

Note that this won't remove that function from subsequent calls to $, as that will generate a fresh jQuery object w/ all available plugins when you call it.

Answer (score 1):

The selector applies to all instances.

Comment: how are you deleting it? or are you simply looking to disable it?